# how to display the value of the bar graph on the top of the graph using flot

Tags: jquery, graph, label, flot

I am using flot api to plot a graph as i increase or decrease my slider(type-"range"). How can i display the value of the graph at the top of the bar graph?
currently i am using this piece of code but it yields no results:

```
    function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
$('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
      position: 'absolute',
      display: 'none',
      fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, Sanserif',
      fontSize: '11px',
      top: y - 23,
      left: x - 3,
      border: '1px solid silver',
      padding: '2px',
      'background-color': 'black'
}).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}

    var previousPoint = null;
    $("#placeholder_1").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
if (item) {
      if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, 'R$ '+y);
      }
} else {
      $("#tooltip").remove();
      previousPoint = null;            
}
});
```

Comment: How does it not work?  And what are you rplot options?

Comment: i am not sure why it doesnt work. What i am trying to do is change the bar graph dynamically using a jquery range slider. I need to display the value of graph just over the graph as it increases or decreases. And this above piece of code is not providing the desired result.